# Не работают стили в браузере в c#

Tags: c#, css, winforms, visual-studio

Добрейший вечерочек. Необходимо отобразить html страницу со стилями в браузере в Windows Forms (vs 2017). Пытался это сделать как в стандартном компоненте WebBrowser, так и в стороннем sdk браузере xulrunner (движок как в Mozilla). Стили отображаются неправильно и дело не в движке.

Вот как оно должно отображаться (браузер Mozilla) :

[image: Правильные стили]

А вот, что получается как в стороннем, так и в стандартном браузере при открытии этой же html страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**, думаю, понятен: почему не отображаются css? Сам файл со стилями подключен к html коду. Прошу дать мне ответ, т.к. потратил на решение данной проблемы не 1 день, но так ничего и не нашел)

П.С. Какими еще способами можно открыть html страницу, чтобы работали css и  был такой же функционал как у WebBrowser?

https://yadi.sk/d/m-8WiPZq3QSrSd --> ссылка на html

https://yadi.sk/d/bWd4mlhg3QSrTE --> ссылка на css

Comment: Убедитесь, что ваш CSS-файл лежит рядом с отображаемым файлом.

Comment: Не знаю какой пример вам привести. WebBrowser просто не отображает большинство(!) стилей при загрузке страницы через данный компонент(например, box-shadow не применяется). Т.е. компонент видит и подключает их, но не применяет, как будто не распознает. 
css определенно лежат около загружаемого html файла. Может быть xulrunner использует браузер по умолчанию(IE какой-нибудь), как и стандартный WebBrowser, и поэтому некоторые стили не отображаются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> в стандартном компоненте WebBrowser

Стандартный `WebBrowser`, если не изменяет память, по умолчанию работает в режиме IE7. Следовательно большинство современных функций в нём недоступны.

Чтобы это исправить можно добавить в заголовок Вашего `html` специальный мета-тег.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Это заставит `WebBrowser` переключиться на работу в режиме последней доступной версии IE. По идее, это должно решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Да, это помогло, но если версия IE ниже 7, то можно установить  CefSharp (как я и сделал).